# EF not create table on database

Tags: entity-framework, code-first

i have probleme with entityframework code first , when i execute my app and save data to database in my controllers it dont't create table for my domain class, i have create context, and add a Dbset variable for my model , i verify all that we need for working with EF but i can't understand wath's the matter , here my code for saving data to dataabase :

```
       foreach (var data in my_friends) {
            entity.Friends.Add(data);

        }
```

my_friends contain a list of "UserFriend" that's it's my domain class, entity it's the context, if you have meet this problem in the past , i like that you help me please !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
foreach (var data in my_friends) {
    entity.Friends.Add(data);        
}
entity.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Personally, I would call `SaveChanges()` outside of the foreach loop. That way all of the database changes are done within a single transaction.